# Using IOC container in silverlight to dynamically load assembly. Is this possible?

Tags: silverlight, ioc-container

I have two silverlight assemblies.
In assembly 1 I have implemented an interface ISnProvider.
In assembly 2 I have a concrete class which implements the ISnProvider.
I plan on having more assemblies which will contain different implementations of ISnProvider.
Assembly 1 has no reference to assembly 2.

When my silverlight app starts up, I want to resolve the ISnProvider interface using an IOC container. Ideally I won't have to recompile my app to use different providers. I don't want to hardcode 'assembly2.dll' in my assembly 1.

Which IOC container will allow me to dynamically load these assemblies using silverlight?

Thank you!

santiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) from Microsoft. That will certainly support your scenario ([example here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115182324/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/20/simple-example-using-managed-extensibility-framework-in-silverlight.aspx)) although it does unfortunately mean you need to use attributes (e.g. [Import] / [Export]) at various places in your code.

[Autofac is available in a Silverlight version](https://web.archive.org/web/20220522134300/https://code.google.com/archive/p/autofac) and I would certainly recommend it for general IOC usage with Silverlight but I've never tried to get it to dynamically load an assembly without a direct reference and I'm not sure if it will support that in Silverlight (I'd love to hear if anyone has accomplished this with Autofac)

You could also use a semi-manual approach - [here's an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150419124236/http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/04/14/10330.aspx) of loading an assembly dynamically in Silverlight **without** an IOC container, which may or may not be useful for you.

Comment: Steve,
thank you. I've read the MEF example you suggest and it certainly would work and solve my problem. I had not even considered MEF for this.

I will give it a shot!

Thank you!

Comment: For anyone interested, I used MEF and I loved it! Works brilliantly!
Thanks for the tip!!